# Is it possible to create a virtual symlink?

Tags: linux, filesystems, symlink

I have a web server that has the following directory structure

```
/var/www/html/www.example.com/wp-content/themes/exampletheme/custom
```

where "custom" is actually a symlink to `/var/www/custom`

This works as expected.

However the theme updater deletes and recreates the entire exampletheme directory, which also deletes the "custom" symlink it contains, which breaks the site.

Is there a way to create a persistent filesystem location (maybe in fstab?) that would make "custom" always appear in the `/var/www/html/www.example.com/wp-content/themes/exampletheme/` directory?

I found something sort of similar using udev, but it only works for devices.

I had considering using cron to keep checking and create it if it's missing, but that's kind of kludgy.

Comment: You can [bind-mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) `/var/www/custom` onto `/var/www/html/www.example.com/wp-content/themes/exampletheme/custom`, that way it cannot be deleted.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [bind-mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount) `/var/www/custom` onto `/var/www/html/www.example.com/wp-content/themes/exampletheme/custom`.

Mount points cannot be deleted, only unmounted, and that (a) requires root privileges and (b) not something programs usually resort to when they can't delete something. So that should work.